# Rails - label form helper insert html tags inside content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-helpers

If I want to insert a `<br/>` as part of the markup inside the label form helper, how do I do it?

Right now when I do this:

```
<%= f.label(:foo, "Foo <br/> Bar: ") %>
```

It outputs `Foo <br/> Bar` as the text of the label.

What I want is the label to have the line break between Foo and Bar. Like this:

> Foo
>
> Bar

Comment: Its not clear what you want: whats the desired generated HTML? Is it `<label>Foo<br />Bar</label>`?

Comment: @CodyCaughlan Yes that's what I want. I don't want the `<br/>` to show up as text. I want the actual line break between Foo and Bar.

Comment: Does this answer help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098290/render-html-in-label-tag-in-rails-3-2-11-html-safe-raw-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string needs to be marked as HTML safe so that Rails will not sanitize the output. Here is the concise way to write the label.

```
<%= f.label :foo, 'Foo <br /> Bar: '.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `raw` method

```
<%= f.label(:foo, raw("Foo <br/> Bar: ")) %>
```